# How do you click a button in a webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, button, browser

For example, using code and no user input, how would I have my program click the "Search" button on google (assuming I've already filled in the search box and am at google.com)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

**If you have an `ID` use this:**

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");
```

**If you have `TagName` use this**

```
 webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

In Web Browser DocumentCompleted event

```
HtmlElement textElement = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("q")[0];
textElement.SetAttribute("value", "your text to search");
HtmlElement btnElement = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnG")[0];
btnElement.InvokeMember("click");
```

**If you have name `Class` use this:**

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton) 
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "button")
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

For adding text in a `TextBox` to search google.com, use this:

```
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gs_tti0").InnerText = "hello world";
```

Comment: shdocvw and mshtml can also come be used!!

Comment: Sorry but what is `webBrowser`?

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I think he meant "webBrowser1"

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
public WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    private void WebForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                webBrowser1.Height = 1000;
                webBrowser1.Width = 1000;
                this.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
                this.webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com.au");
            }
            catch
            { }
```

Write down the following function in your c# form:

```
public void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

        HtmlElement textElement = webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("q")[0];
        textElement.SetAttribute("value", "mlm company");
        HtmlElement btnElement = webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnG")[0];
        btnElement.InvokeMember("click");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `InvokeMember` and others, if your web page has issues responding when called by `ID` or `Class`, you can try using `{TAB}` & `{ENTER}` using the `SendKeys` class within .NET. I've written a lot of scripts for web pages and have found that I've had to use a combination of both (even though `SendKeys` is far messier than the methods in @AleWin's answer).

[Here is the link to the SendKeys class.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx)