# How do I use Document.GetElementById("NAME").Click?

Tags: c#, click, getelementbyid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you click a button in a webbrowser control in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271737/how-do-you-click-a-button-in-a-webbrowser-control-in-c)

I tried just doing it normally, but it kept telling me it needed to be on the other side of a = or +=. How do I fix this?

The code I'm using is:
    browser.Document.GetElementById("ap_h").Click;

Comment: I think code in the question got lost while you where typing it... Consider adding it again (incliding type of Document object).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The piece of code you are looking for is:

**Invoke a method in the DOM-Element**

```
// The WebBrowser control
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser;

// Perform a click on an element
HtmlDocument document = webBrowser.Document;
document.GetElementById("id_of_element").InvokeMember("Click");
```

The code above performs the click in the WebBrowser Control for you.

---

**Assign an event handler**

If you want to assign an event handler:

```
document.GetElementById("id_of_element").Click 
                             += new HtmlElementEventHandler(el_Click);
```

with:

```
void el_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: This worked for me on this even "DocumentCompleted"t:                                                                             private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Button1").Click
                             += new HtmlElementEventHandler(el_Click);
        }