# How to get the value of document.getElementById('id01') using the linkbutton the was inside the gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

i wan to get the value of the document.getElementById('id01') using the linkbutton that was inside the gridview and here's the code that i want to get

```
<div id="id01" class="modal">
    <form class="modal-content animate">

        <div class="imgcontainer"></div>
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">×</span>
        <div class="container"> 
           <p> This message was rejected by the recipient email system. Please check the recipient's email address and  try resending this message, or contact the recipient directly</p>
            <p> A problem occurred while delivering this message to this email address. Try sending this message again. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.</p>
            <p> The domain name in the email address is incorrect. Check the address.</p>
            <p> Sorry, I couldn't find any host named like(Sample@email.com). Please check the email address and try again.</p>
            <p> The server has tried to deliver this message, without success, and has stopped trying. Please try sending this message again.<br /> If the problem continues, contact your helpdesk.</p>
            <button type="button" runat="server" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" id="btncancel">Cancel</button>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here's the code on my grivdiew

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <<pre><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"  runat="server" CommandArgument="EmailDetails" CommandName="DisplayEmail" Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>'></asp:LinkButton>


            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject Email" />--%>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sender" HeaderText="Receiver" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="Date and Time Sent" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateReceive" HeaderText="Date and Time Received" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailHeader" HeaderText="Details" />

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
```

and here's the javascript code

```
script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

and here's my backend code

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DisplayEmail")
        {


        }

        }
```

can anyone help me to get the document.getElementById('id01') and display the modal when clicking the linkbutton.
for now im using the button that is outside the grid to display the modal

here's the code for the button

```
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" runat="server">List Email Errors</button>
```

Comment: [look here or do a google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271875/how-do-i-use-document-getelementbyidname-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using jQuery.

```
var targets = $('#id01, #id02');
targets.on('click,touch', () => {
     $(this).hide();
});
```

Also, you overwrite modal by declaring it twice here -

```
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');
```