# WebBrowser control: click won't work

Tags: c#, winforms, click, webbrowser-control, invoke

I used the DocumentComplete event to AutoComplete a form. Everything is OK except the checkbox. The html code is the following:

```
<span class="myClass" style="padding-left: 12px; vertical-align: bottom; cursor: pointer;">
<input id="ich_liebe_dich" type="checkbox" name="ich$liebe$dich">
<label for="ich_liebe_dich"> MyLabel</label>
</span>
```

I tried using:

```
webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("ich_liebe_dich").InvokeMember("click");
```

and

```
webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("ich$liebe$dich").InvokeMember("click");
```

and also:

```
foreach (HtmlElement current in webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName(tag))
{
    if (current.GetAttribute(attr).Equals(attName))
        current.InvokeMember(invoke);
}
```

where attr="id", tag="input", invoke="click" and attName= either "ich_liebe_dich" or "ich$liebe$dich".

The best I got was a transiently - just for a fraction of a second - checked checkbox. Why would this happen? Any solutions?

Comment: Pay attention to the method name.  It is ById, not ByName.

Answer (score 1):

leppie's answer made me curious because I've never read anywhere about InvokeMember("check") and I googled it! The first answer I got is this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/750b11dc-08f8-4cb4-bcaf-80c91f0fd425/

I read the article and found a solution...
If I add this line on DocumentCompleted event then everything works ok!

```
if (webbrowser.ReadyState==WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
```

It seems that the page has frames and the DocumentCompleted event fires before the whole page is loaded.

edit: I forgot to mention that the code I used (and works) is the following:

```
webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("ich_liebe_dich").InvokeMember("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had already answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271737/how-do-you-click-a-button-in-a-webbrowser-control-in-c/11273176#11273176)

webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

**if you have id use this:**

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");
```

**if you have tagname use this**

```
 webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

In Web Browser DocumentCompleted event

```
HtmlElement textElement = webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("q")[0];
textElement.SetAttribute("value", "your text to search");
HtmlElement btnElement = webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnG")[0];
btnElement.InvokeMember("click");
```

**if you have name class use this:**

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton) 
 {
     if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "button")
    {
       element.InvokeMember("click");
     }
 }
```

for add text in textbox google.com use this:

```
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gs_tti0").InnerText = "hello world";
```