# WPF .GetElementById()

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click

Im programming in WPF (C#) in VS2012

I tried to use this:

[How do you click a button in a webbrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271737/how-do-you-click-a-button-in-a-webbrowser-control-in-c)

To click button on webbrowser but

1. `.GetElementById` gives me an error.

   I add: `using System.Windows.Forms;` and assembly them, but it don't change anything for me.
2. I think im gonna have a problem with this as well: `.InvokeMember("click");`

All I've found on the web is that:

http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/m_telerik_windows_documents_formatproviders_html_parsing_dom_idocument_getelementbyid.html

But I don't know exactly how i can assembly that to VS2012, bcus there are no build in API references in VS2012.

Comment: You are using WPF not Winforms That method is not available in the [WPF version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) of the Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Windows Forms WebBrowser instead of WPF WebBrowser host in WindowsFormHosted control in the WPF app and then you can access those members.

Comment: You surely don't need to add a reference to "System.Windows.Forms"

Comment: Ok, but when i do this its not actually a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser object its System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost and i cant actually do something usefull with them

Comment: I solve problem

Xaml:

xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration" 

Code behind:

            System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            windowsFormsHost.Child = Browser;

Answer (score 0):

```
// reference :
/// https://gist.github.com/sphingu/5781036
----------------------------------------------------
// Using WebBrowser for Crowling in WPF
----------------------------------------------------
<WebBrowser Cursor="Arrow" Name="MyBrowser" LoadCompleted="MyBrowser_OnLoadCompleted" />
----------------------------------------------------
// useful methods of WebBrowser
----------------------------------------------------
MyBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://google.com"));

private void MyBrowser_OnLoadCompleted(object sender,NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        ...
        // return source of loaded page in WebBrowser
        var document=(IHTMLDocument3) MyBrowser.Document;

        //Get Element and set its value
        document.getElementById("userName").setAttribute("value","myusername");

        //get Button on page and fire its click event
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();

        // Invoke javascript function on page loaded on WebBrowser
        MyBrowser.InvokeScript("submitform",param1,param2,...);

        //get data from table in page
         _innerHtmldata =
                ((IHTMLDocument3) MyBrowser.Document).getElementById("datatable")
                                                     .innerHTML;

}
```

Comment: Please add some information about how your solution works.