# C# Classname of an img class

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

How do i get the classname of a img class?

```
<img class="getthis" alt="notthis" src="img/x.gif" />
```

the  code below isn't working:

```
HtmlElementCollection classButtones = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement elemente in classButtones)
{
    if (elemente.GetAttribute("className") == ("getthis")){ }
}
```

also imgclassName doesn't work..

Comment: `className` != `class`. (And why the brackets around `"getthis"`?

Comment: Is this even using `HtmlAgilityPack` or the built-in DOM of a `WebBrowser` control?

Comment: Its not using the HtmlAgilityPack. But i think the agilitypack might be able to solve this question..

Comment: `className` should be correct, since WebBrowser uses the IE engine which makes the `class` attribute a special case. Are you sure the DOM is fully loaded? Your code works for me using `google.com` and some random class name I found in that page.

Answer (score 1):

You `if` statement doesn't contain the correct condition. You could try the following one:

```
if(elemente.GetAttribute("class") == "getthis"){ }
```

The `className` is not an attribute. While `class` is an attribute. Furthermore, you don't need the extra parenthesis.

Comment: @JurreSanders I don't think that you are correct. Please give it a go and let me know. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271737/how-do-you-click-a-button-in-a-webbrowser-control ive tried ur code, but it isn't working :(