# How to trigger datatable row with java?

Tags: java, c#, datatable, triggers, row

I am trying to read data from a website. I can reach all HTML elements on the page. There is a DataTable on the page. When I select a row from DataTable, another div appears on the right side, but I can't trigger a click event for the row. There is no error, but the DataTable row doesn't select.

If I choose a row with the mouse, the request is sending with AJAX and the response appears on the right side in the div. All pages seem XHTML. I researched and site developed by Java. I wrote an App with C# using webbrowser.

How can I trigger a click event of row on a DataTable?

Comment: can you show us some of your code what you have tried, it will be very difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: What language do you use? java or C#?

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/Bv6mjG.jpg

http://i.hizliresim.com/ZMQglz.jpg

Comment: I am using C# Language

Answer (score 0):

You need to know ajax request send to server when you click the row. You can find request by firebug(firefox) or any browser plugin.

Comment: I added to Images, you can see

Comment: see this link :

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271737/how-do-you-click-a-button-in-a-webbrowser-control

Comment: I can trigger buttons or other element but i cant trigger datatable row, that is my porblem